# Hadoop Standalone Mode gives Connection Error

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce

When I run the the following in standalone mode,

```
*phoenix@phoenix-Aspire-E1-570:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar 
share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.2.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'*
```

It is giving me the following error,

```
15/12/06 22:45:45 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at 
localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
15/12/06 22:45:46 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 
localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. 
Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is 
RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
15/12/06 22:45:47 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. 
Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10,
sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

I used all the default settings. I was trying the same steps mentioned in the following page for standalone mode.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation

Note: As per my understanding, we don't need to start any daemon in standalone mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue. The issue was with mapred-site.xml. The mapreduce.framework.name property should be local in the case of standalone mode. I mentioned yarn there. Once I changed it, it worked fine.